# Is it possible to create platform specific views?

Tags: maui, .net-maui

In UWP, device specific views can be created by placing those views into their respective folders or appending the relevant device name to the file name.
I don't see any information on doing the equivalent with MAUI as regards platform specific views only platform specific code.
Is this a thing ?

The closest I can get is using preprocessor directives and giving the files unique names. This means there are still multiple code behind files unfortunately.

So -

#if ANDROID

```
      await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1Windows());
```

#elif WINDOWS

```
      await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1Android());
```

#endif

Comment: you can use the new Handler mechanism, or still use XF Style Custom Renderers: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Using-Custom-Renderers-in-.NET-MAUI

Comment: I am interested in hearing, did you find a solution for handling platforms specific views without having multiple different code behind files?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but you can also try using platform specific Xaml as per here -  https://youtu.be/l58nO0Hi7W0?t=4264

Comment: Yes, this can be done: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74823801/4308455

Answer (score 1):

It's a thing.
The default MAUI projects provide a platform specific folder you can put platform specific code in.

If you want something more complicated, like your platform-named folders or files, you can edit your csproj to include or exclude files by name & platform.

There are examples of both file and folder-based targeting in the [Configure multi-targeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/configure-multi-targeting) docs:

Here's the combined view from [Combine filename and folder multi-targeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/configure-multi-targeting#combine-filename-and-folder-multi-targeting) that excludes files and folders that include platform names that don't match the current target.

```
<ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net6.0-android')) != true">
   <Compile Remove="**\**\*.Android.cs" />   <None Include="**\**\*.Android.cs" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(DefaultExcludesInProjectFolder)" />
   <Compile Remove="**\Android\**\*.cs" />   <None Include="**\Android\**\*.cs" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(DefaultExcludesInProjectFolder)" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net6.0-ios')) != true AND $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net6.0-maccatalyst')) != true"> 
   <Compile Remove="**\**\*.iOS.cs" />   <None Include="**\**\*.iOS.cs" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(DefaultExcludesInProjectFolder)" />  
   <Compile Remove="**\iOS\**\*.cs" />   <None Include="**\iOS\**\*.cs" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(DefaultExcludesInProjectFolder)" />  
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-windows')) != true ">
    <Compile Remove="**\*.Windows.cs" />   <None Include="**\*.Windows.cs" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(DefaultExcludesInProjectFolder)" />
    <Compile Remove="**\Windows\**\*.cs" />   <None Include="**\Windows\**\*.cs" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(DefaultExcludesInProjectFolder)" /> 
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm being dumb but I can't get it to work with xaml files. VS just throws up errors.

Comment: What errors? Did you exclude the xaml files from the unneeded platforms? The code snippet I provided excluded only cs files but can be easily extended to other file types

Comment: "App' does not contain a definition for 'InitializeComponent' and no accessible extension method 'InitializeComponent' accepting a first argument of type 'App' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
"

Comment: "Unknown type 'ContentPage' in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui". This is only for the page.xaml if placed in the Windows folder.

Comment: This does not work for views (at least not without some additional work). Only for classes that are not being called based on their naming (setup of views and viewmodels in MauiProgram.cs), such as a service, which is also what microsoft uses as an example in their documentation.