# .NET MAUI: can we also have platform-specific XAML?

Tags: xaml, maui

I read, that we can use platform-specific C# in MAUI projects, but I have the need to use a platform-specific XAML file. Couldn't find anything in the docs.

*Background:*
On Android a SwipeView inside a ListView throws a Java error when removing an item from the bound ObservableCollection ("The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."), so I use a CollectionView here (no error).
On iOS, the CollectionView does extend outside the lower end of the page, when used together with other elements on a page (it seems, on iOS a CollectionView does want to take the full screen height), so I have to use ListView here. On iOS though, the above mentioned error does not occur.

Comment: That should be possible, yes. Just write two different versions of your XAML, one for iOS and one for Android. Then, during runtime, just instantiate the right one based on the system you're running on.

Comment: Just as a general rule, I would advise against nesting scrollable views inside one another. For example, the docs for ScrollView state that you shouldn't nest it with CollectionView, ListView, etc. and I think that probably also applies to SwipeViews: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/scrollview?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: @ewerspej - perhaps say a bit more about what maui feature or keyword would be used to *"instantiate the right one based on the system you're running on"*.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve When I find the time, I'll write up an answer. Explaining this isn't so easy in the comments. In short: Pages and Views can be instantiated by calling their constructor and either pushing them on the navigation stack or adding them as a child to another View in the code behind. To decide which one should be instantiated (by calling `new SomePage()`), a runtime platform check could be used: `if(DeviceInfo.Current.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android){...}`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can achieve this with separate XAML files for each platform. Just write two different versions of your XAML, one for iOS and one for Android. Then, during runtime, instantiate the right one based on the system your application is running on.

## Pages

For entire pages, you could just create one version of the page for Android and one for iOS (and other ones for the remaining platforms respectively, if needed).

### Android Page

Let's call the Android page ***HelloFromAndroid.xaml***:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiSamples.Views.Platform.HelloFromAndroid"
             Title="HelloFromAndroid"
             Shell.PresentationMode="Modal">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Hello from Android!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

### iOS Page

The iOS version will be called ***HelloFromiOS.xaml***:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiSamples.Views.Platform.HelloFromiOS"
             Title="HelloFromiOS"
             Shell.PresentationMode="Modal">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Hello from iOS!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

### Opening the platform-specific pages

You can either decide which version to open during runtime, or you can use multi-targeting/conditional compilation. You do this from your code behind, e.g. the ***MainPage.xaml.cs***:

#### Runtime decision

```cs
private async void OpenHelloView(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new HelloFromAndroid());
    }

    if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new HelloFromiOS());
    }
}
```

#### Conditional compilation

```cs
private async void OpenHelloView(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
#if ANDROID
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new HelloFromAndroid());
#elif IOS
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new HelloFromiOS());
#endif
}
```

This version is the preferred way, because the compiled code only contains the required platform-specific call.

## Views

For Views, this is a little more complicated, but also possible.

If you need a platform-specific View, you cannot add it to your page's XAML and instead need to instantiate it dynamically during runtime from the code-behind and add it as a child to another View or a Layout.

#### Android View

Let's create a View called ***ViewAndroid***:

**XAML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiSamples.Views.Platform.ViewAndroid">

  <Label
    Text="Hello from Android!"
    VerticalOptions="Center" 
    HorizontalOptions="Center" />

</ContentView>
```

#### iOS View

And let's also create a View called ***ViewiOS***:

**XAML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiSamples.Views.Platform.ViewiOS">

  <Label
    Text="Hello from iOS!"
    VerticalOptions="Center" 
    HorizontalOptions="Center" />

</ContentView>
```

#### Page with platform-specific View

Now, let's create a Page that consumes the platform-specific Views. First, we create some XAML. For simplicity, I'm using an empty `VerticalStackLayout` that I give a name using the `x:Name` property:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiSamples.Views.Platform.PageWithPlatformSpecificView"
             Title="PageWithPlatformSpecificView"
             Shell.PresentationMode="Modal">
    <VerticalStackLayout x:Name="VerticalLayout" />
</ContentPage>
```

Now, I can access the `VerticalLayout` field from my code-behind and add child elements to it. This can again be done dynamically either via a runtime decision or via conditional compilation.

##### Runtime decision

```cs
public partial class PageWithPlatformSpecificView : ContentPage
{
    public PageWithPlatformSpecificView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android)
        {
            VerticalLayout.Add(new ViewAndroid());
        }
        
        if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
        {
            VerticalLayout.Add(new ViewiOS());
        }
    }
}
```

##### Conditional compilation

```cs
public partial class PageWithPlatformSpecificView : ContentPage
{
    public PageWithPlatformSpecificView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

#if ANDROID
        VerticalLayout.Add(new ViewAndroid());
#elif IOS
        VerticalLayout.Add(new ViewiOS());
#endif
    }
}
```

Again, the conditional compilation is the preferred way.

## Alternative approaches

### XAML-only using `<OnPlatform>`

You can also do this in XAML, but beware that this approach will include all views of all platforms in the app bundle, e.g.:

```xml
<ContentView>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
        <On Platform="Android">
            <android:ViewAndroid />
        </On>
        <On Platform="iOS">
            <ios:ViewiOS />
        </On>
    </OnPlatform>
</ContentView>
```

The same works with `<OnIdiom>` and other markup.

### Multi-targeting

Technically, you could also use [filename-based multi-targeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/configure-multi-targeting?view=net-maui-7.0#configure-filename-based-multi-targeting) to only include the right version of the XAML in the final build.

However, it requires a complex setup in the *.csproj* file to configure multi-targeting for XAML files, which is not officially supported. I have written an answer on this for a similar problem that deals with platform-specific resource dictionaries here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74338355/4308455

## Summary

As you can see, there are different approaches and possibilities to accomplish this with platform-specific XAML. It's not exactly the same as platform-specific C# code, but it can be useful for certain scenarios. I hope this helps you and anyone else with similar requirements.

I've tried this myself and added the code to my [MAUI samples repository](https://github.com/ewerspej/maui-samples), if you're interested.

Comment: Perfect. Good suggestions. Also, I was looking for keywords to suggest when someone wants more resources. `maui xamarin runtime platform check android ios` might be a good google search.

Comment: Wow - thank you so much for these extensive explanations. I tried both versions - both work like a breeze! Just a little difference: I use the conditional compilation as suggested and I had to put the page calls into the viewmodel (for MVVM) and I had to add the routes in MauiProgramm.cs and AppShell.xaml.cs.

Comment: Yes, how you actually implement it is up to you, my answer was only of exemplary nature. I'm glad it solves your problem.

Comment: Can conditional compilation be done in XAML so we can include specific-platform views inside other views in XAML?

Comment: @MEMOGAMER000 No, but you can create different ContentViews for each platform in the platform-specific folders. They should then automatically be picked up as long as they share the same namespace and class name.

Comment: @MEMOGAMER000 Alternatively, you could also try to use the `<OnPlatform>` markup extension, I haven't tried that for platform-specific XAML yet.

Comment: I have tried both of <OnPlatform> and <OnIdiom> XAML markup extensions, and I'm shocked by their result! Now, I can have different views for different platforms and idioms sharing the same view model and namespaces without writing additional boilerplate code and XAML. You must consider adding this to your answer if your time permits. Thank you very much @Julian

Comment: Done. I have also added an example to my samples repository and I will write a blog post about this in the next days, which I already had planned.