# .Net Maui Adaptive Page Layouts on Different Platforms

Tags: c#, .net, maui, multiplatform

i was searching alot but didnt find anything helpfull.
I try to explain my question with an example.

Im writing a program with .net maui for pc and mobile. On the pc i want it on 1 page, on the left side a list with items and on the right a screen "item view" and for the mobile a multipage layout. first page the item lsit and the item view on the second settigns on the third etc.

I wrote both of it but im strugling to combine it. I dont want to projects where i have to edit everything 2 times when i have an update oder something like that. i thought about it to make everything in 1 project and a small piece of code that switches the diffrent pages depending on the platform but there have to be a good solution.

Anyone a hint or idea? or seen something like that?

Thanks alot!

Edit:

[image: ScreenShot PC Beta]

This is the Version for the PC with WinForms. Here is everything on one single page. this is how i want it also later with .Net Maui. The onlything is a popup window for the settings.

The Verison for the Phone Is a tabbed multi Page app. I add photos from the whiteboard. (Only backend exists atm)

[image: ItemAdd Drawing]

[image: Search DB Drawing]

The Tabbed layout should look a bit like the Clock App on the iPhone. On the PC version all elements are on the same page. Thats good bcs there is enough space. But i want for the Phone app to seperate it. (Searchbar & list with results, Item View / add item, settings) Like the pictures from the whiteboard.

I dont have any relevant design code bcs atm only the backend exists on the maui app. for the pages i just used the default pages from microsoft with editet text so i see if its the correct page.

Comment: Please provide more information about what you're trying to do and show some code. It's easier to explain with code (always as text) and screenshots/mock ups. Otherwise, your question is too broad and unfocused. It would probably help to read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: See https://blog.ewers-peters.de/add-responsive-layouts-to-your-maui-app for some background and ideas

Comment: This might be relevant or at least serve as inspiration as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74815868/net-maui-can-we-also-have-platform-specific-xaml/74823801#74823801

Comment: @Julian upadted the question. so u mean the way i tried with multiple pages and activate / deactivate dependig on the platform was the right direction?

ah btw nice name hahah

Comment: You may need to set different MainPage for different platforms to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

For the specific situation you want, a list with details for a list item, use a [`FlyoutPage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/flyoutpage)

> The .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI) FlyoutPage is a page that
> manages two related pages of information – a flyout page that presents
> items, and a detail page that presents details about items on the
> flyout page.
>
> A FlyoutPage has two layout behaviors:
>
> In a popover layout, the detail page covers or partially covers the flyout page. Selecting an item on the flyout page will navigate to the corresponding detail page. Apps running on phones always use this layout behavior.
>
> In a split layout, the flyout page is displayed on the left and the detail page is on the right. Apps running on tablets or the desktop can use this layout behavior, with Windows using it by default.

By default, the Page will automatically choose the best layout behavior for the platform.

Comment: Yeah looks good this is what i need on the phone. but the problem is how i seperate it that on the pc is all on one page and on the phone a flyoutpage. but this is helpfull aswell. thanks!

Comment: Read the text again. This behavior is built-in. One page on the PC or tablet and Flyout on the phone using the same XAML source

Comment: I treid for 2 houres and now i realize we dont think about the same XD. with list i dont mean the tabs on the side. WIth list i mean an actual list with item from the DB. like in winforms u use a "listBox" like a shopping list. In the first Pic u see in the PC version on the left the listbox.

Comment: The flyout page is just a normal Content Page. You can use any control here. You can use a CollectionView that is filled from a data source like a database or similar.